# connect facebook to android eclipse

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

I´m making a project to Eclipse (Android) and I want to connect facebook with my app, for example, I need to receive all post of my facebook account in my app, but I don´t know how.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you successfully login through your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the official facebook library from gihub. Then create an app. on facebook.com 
You will get the key. Use that key in your Java code to get the access token. Now, use this token to log in to your facebook account. Then you can use the graph API or the FQL to get the post from facebook. Also there are 100s of examples on stack overflow itself.

Comment: Can you explain better with some example?sorry, but i´m begginer on the android apps.

Comment: @Diogo but i guess u can search it as well... there are so many examples around.

Comment: Aamir shah I found a good example, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ but I can´t have my password, I don´t know how to install openssl correctly :s

Comment: @Diogo the link which u shared is too good... for openssl just install it

Comment: thanks for the links ;) after install openssl in my pc I put the following text in my CMD: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Diogo\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64, but isn´t work, I can´t have my password :s sorry, but I'm a newbie